# Cloud9 (c9.io) SSH permission denied

Tags: cloud9-ide

We have been using Cloud9 pretty heavily hear at the shop.  However today all of our workspaces on one of our servers are now inaccessible.  If I try SSH Settings and go click on 'apply', I get this:
`Error: {"connect":{"ok":false,"errmsg":"Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server [myusername]@[server_ip]","code":255,"stdout":"","stderr":"Warning: Permanently added '[my-ip]' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n"},"ok":false}`

The only think I can think that happened was permissions were changed on all the files within the folder this workspace was accessing to 777.  Well almost all before it was realized what was done.  Do permissions play a role in it?  Just don't know what else it would be since one minute it was working and the next it was not.  I did try deleting the workspace and recreating with no luck. (won't even create the space because it cannot connect anymore). I doubled check that the ssh key was still authorized.  Any ideas?  really need this up and running as we have pretty much become dependent on c9 to be or main tool.
thanks.

Comment: It appears you're using an SSH workspace, and Cloud9 cannot reach it anymore. Can you try SSH'ing into it yourself using your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem connecting when using Putty

Comment: it was indeed the folder permissions.  had to change my user folder to 711

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a permissions issue.  I had to change the user folder I was trying to connect to , to 711.  Once we did that, everything is up and running.